# MS BotFramework: collecting users credentials

Tags: botframework

Apologies for the lack of code or detail but I honestly don't know where to start!

I am building a bot to run a couple of reports and update a bunch of stuff in SharePoint (currently 2013 but moving to Online later in 2017).

I don't want to store them in plain text within the folder structure of my bot but I don't want them visible when you type them into the chat bot either.

Is there a way to asterisk out the password as the user types it in?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, you want to mask the password input for your users. If any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

So it seems that there is a similar question in GitHub at [[Question] Masking Password field in Adaptive Card?](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3102)

> Password masking is not currently a feature. We recommend using the Sign-in Card workflow.

Using Sign-in card:

```
Activity replyToConversation = message.CreateReply("Should go to conversation");
replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();

CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
{
    Value = $"https://<OAuthSignInURL",
    Type = "signin",
    Title = "Connect"
};

cardButtons.Add(plButton);

SigninCard plCard = new SigninCard(title: "You need to authorize me", button: plButton);

Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);

var reply = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyToConversation);
```

Then leverage https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot in your bot for authentication.

Comment: That is totally what I needed!